# Is there any relation between Revati nakshatra and goddesses Revati

Tags: astrology, goddess

[Revati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revati_(nakshatra)) is one of the nakshatra in Hinduism, especially astrology.

[Revati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revati) is a goddess in Hinsuism and is a wife to lord Balarama.

Is there any relation between the Revati goddess nd the star Revati?

Comment: Nakshatras being consort of Moon God is a parable, a metaphor of Puranas, just like Brahman of Vedas is personified as Brahma in Puranas. Now, we know with science that constellations are made of stars just like Sun and in astrophysics and Vedic astrology impact Sun and earth and its beings because of their space-time bend curvatures along the horizon belt. The purpose of puranic stories are to explain complex metaphysical concepts in layman's terms to a common humans in inner oblivion who lack deep insights.

Answer (score 5):

Revati, who is wife of Balarama, is daughter of King Kakudmi.

From one of the wiki links in the question:

> **Revati, within Hinduism, is daughter of King Kakudmi and consort of
>   the Balarama,** the elder brother of Krishna. Her account is given
>   within a number of Puranic texts such as the Mahabharata and Bhagavata
>   Purana.

But, Revati, one of the 27 Nakshatras and who is one of the 27 consorts of Chandra, is a daughter of Daksha Prajapati. Daksha gave all his 27 daughters (who are the 27 Nakshatras) to Chandra in marriage.

This is mentioned in various Puranas.

Quoting from the book ["Essence of Matsya Purana"](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/matsya/bookview.php?chapnum=7):

> *7    Chandra’s origin, wedding with Stars, Tara and birth of Budha & their progeny*
>
> Suta Mahamuni desired to know about Chandra Deva who was in charge of
>   Pirtu Lokas. As Brahma instructed one of his ‘Manasa Putras’ Maharshi
>   Atri to take up take up some responsibility to ‘Srishti’, the Maharshi
>   performed an ‘Anutthar’ (unprecedented) ‘Tapasya’due to which the
>   Unique Paramatma whom Brahma, Vishnu, Rudra and Surya reside was
>   pleased to materialise ‘Ashtamaamsu Shishu’ or Chandra Deva from the
>   mind’s eye of Shiva and as a result flowed out a stream of
>   illumination from the Maharshi’s physical eyes. That radiance filled
>   up all the ‘dishas’ (directions) and a woman appeared who was
>   conceived and confined for three hundred years; as she could not carry
>   the child, she sacrificed her life and Lord Brahma pulled out a
>   ‘Purusha’ of extraordinary blaze with arms decorated with ‘Audhaas’and
>   placed him on a chariot driven by thousand horses with
>   ‘Vedamantras’and took him away to Brahmaloka. There Brahmarshis
>   declared that the newly arrived Youth was their Chief and as Pitaras,
>   Gandharvas and personified Aushodhis arrived, all the Devas and Brahma
>   extolled him by ‘Somadaivitya’ Mantras. With the ‘Stutis’ (praises),
>   Chandra’s glow increased manifold and‘Aoushadhis’ started germinating
>   on the Earth in the nights and the Chandra mandala became by the day
>   from Amavasya to Pournami and waned till next moon-fall till the
>   moon-rise again.
>   **Daksha, the son of Pracheta, gave away his twenty seven daughters in wedding to Chandra.**

And, from ["Essence of Varaha Purana"](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/varaha/bookview.php?chapnum=23):

> *23    Daksha’s curse to Moon, reappearance and worship on Pournamis*
>
> One of Lord Brahma’s distinguished Manasa Putras named Sage Atri begot
>   Soma (Moon) who too was illustrious. **Prajapati Daksha married off
>   all his twenty seven daughters to Soma.** But the latter was ignoring
>   all the daughters, excepting Devi Rohini. The rest of them complained
>   to their father Daksha who reprimanded Soma to behave but Soma ignored
>   the repeated warnings of Daksha. Out of exasperation, Daksha cursed
>   Soma to gradually decline and finally disappear.

So, both the Revatis are not the same.